# Can I add a partition to an external hard drive without reformatting the existing one?

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, external-hard-drive, formatting

I have Windows 8 on my laptop and I want to transfer some data from a Mac using an external hard drive. I have a 1TB drive that I could use, but it's NTFS. I would like to partition it and reformat that partition to exfat. However, my drive has a lot of things on it that I don't want to lose and it's too big for me to back it up on my laptop.

Can I make an empty partition and reformat it without touching the other partition containing files?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert NTFS partition to a EXFAT partition without wiping it?  **If you reformat the drive that is going to format the drive obviously.**  There are tools to support NTFS on OS X.  There are tools to convert NTFS partitions to other partition schema without reformatting the drive.  These tools are third-party.  You should clarify your question with regards to what exactly you want to achieve and avoid asking for a software recommendation.

Comment: @Ramhound Obviously if I reformat, it'll reformat. The question is if I can break up the NTFS partition and make two of them, one with my things and one empty, and then reformat the empty one without messing with the other (now smaller) one.

Comment: Are you asking if you can shrink the existing partition, and create a new partition, from the unallocated space created be shrinking the existing partition?  If you have enough free space, you can do that, using the built-in disk management tools within Windows 8.

Comment: @Ramhound If you read the body of the question, I think it's pretty clear that's what they're asking. (And you're the one who's suggesting something that'd turn this into a software recommendation question; the original question contains no trace of that.)

Comment: @Jefromi - I am telling you it isn't clear. *If it was clear I would just submit an answer instead of submitting comments*  Have you simply tried to shrink the existing partition?  Your ability to do this would depend on the level of file fragmentation of the partition itself obviously.

Comment: @Ramhound My hard drive currently has only one partition, in NTFS, and it has plenty of free space. I want to have a second partition in EXFAT, and I just want to know if it's possible to do that without losing the data I currently have on my drive because I don't have the ability to back it up somewhere at the moment.

Comment: @Kareen - Shrink the existing partition then partition the unallocated space.

Comment: @Ramhound The question says "Can I make an empty partition and reformat it without touching the other partition containing files?" I think that makes it pretty clear that "sure, you can shrink the existing partition" is an answer. The fact that the OP didn't know that the secret word was "shrink" doesn't change that.

Comment: @Jefromi - *It isn't clear to me.*  Which is the reason I asked for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I make an empty partition

Yes. You can shrink the existing NTFS partition and then create a new partitioning on the freshly created unpartitioned space. There are several ways to do this, including software include in the windows OS itself.

(So if you have access to a windows installation there is no need to look for 3<sup>rd</sup> party software such as pqmagic)

I highly recommended you backup **before** doing this though.

> and reformat it without touching the other partition containing files?

Technically: Yes.

However I recommend a backup first. And after that it is easiest (and probably fastest) to simply wipe and restore from backup.

Comment: Is the risk just that you'll accidentally do the wrong thing, or are the operations risky somehow even if done correctly?

Comment: @Jefromi - Users make mistakes when they are not 100% sure of what to do, and even when they do know what to do, they can still do the wrong thing by mistake.

Comment: @Jefromi Both. User error can lead to data loss. And a power cut at the wrong moment can also spoil your day.